# A line of code with just an integer before Semicolon in c++

Tags: c++

For example:

```
1;
```

what does it do?is the integer saved anywhere in the memory?

Comment: This statement has no visible effect. It evaluates the expression, it evaluates to 1, and then it discards the result.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

That line of code has no observable effect in the C++ standard's abstract machine.

Compilers are free to store it in memory, or not.  If stored, it cannot be accessed via any behavior defined under the C++ standard.  Most compilers with reasonable optimization settings enabled will treat it as a noop, and decent quality compilers should issue warnings if your warning level is reasonable.

---

In general, the behavior of C++ code is described in the standard as the behavior of an abstract machine.  This is pretty common in languages.  But unlike some other abstract machine languages, C++ leaves many operations on the abstract machine *undefined*.

Standards compliant compilers are free to generate any machine code (or whatever) that behaves as the abstract machine does, insofar as that machine's behavior is defined by the standard.

This means things that have no observable effects can be eliminated completely by a C++ compiler.  This includes the statement `3;`.

Even things with observable effects can be eliminated, so long as the observable effects remain.  For example:

```
char const* a = "123";
for (int i = 0; i < 3; ++i) {
  std::cout << a[i];
}
std::cout << "\n";
```

the observable effect here is that `123\n` is printed.  The variable `a` and the fact it is pointing to a read only buffer containing the bytes `'1'`, `'2'`, `'3'`, `'\0'` are not **directly** observable.  Few things are.

More importantly, as the compiler can see this entire function, it can the only thing done is that the characters are passed to `std::cout`.

So this buffer and the variable `a` can be eliminated, so long as the program behaves *as-if* it would, up to undefined behavior.

Many of the things left undefined permit really aggressive optimizations.  They can also generate really hard to track down bugs.

---

There is a "naive" transformation of your C++ code to C/assembly code.  Many people will imaging it when asked what a compiler does, and call anything that doesn't follow those steps "optimization".

However, this doesn't describe what any reasonable C++ compiler does in a reasonable probject.

Comment: Read that as "noop" and not "no-op" and got a little chuckle. +1

Comment: so how come 
const char*a ="123";
has a meaning?where is "123" saved?

Comment: @dangha: In your executable. That is to say, it might not be saved if `a` is unused (optimization when no observable effect)

Comment: @dangha That is a different question.  That isn't a statement consisting only of a number followed by a semicolon.  That statement, depending on what follows, could have observable effects in the abstract machine; it could also not have such effects.  C++ doesn't define a mapping between code and assembler, it describes the behavior of an abstract machine, and compilers build machine code that does what the abstract machine does.  C++ permits certain operations to be undefined, allowing massive optimizations by the compiler.

Comment: thanks but there is one more thing that I dont understand. how can a pointer have "123" as its value?

Comment: @dangha good question.  Go click on "ask a question" to your top left.  Or search for it.